# Is code without usage of DuplicateRecordFields extension compatible if extension is enabled?

Tags: haskell

More exactly : is there case of code that would compile WITHOUT this extension enabled but would not compile anymore WITH the extension ?

In other words, does it break  Haskell code upward compatibility ?

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based as the question seems to invite a discussion about what should and shouldn't be part of the core language and why, which doesn't have an objective answer.

Note that the argument "doesn't break any code when turned on" traditionally isn't an argument for inclusion into the core language. This is true for *many* GHC language extensions. The fact that it doesn't break anything isn't sufficient reason to expand the standard.

Comment: @Cubic : maybe the title gives the feeling of opinion based question, but the content  clearly ask a non opinion base question. I will update the title to stick to it then

Comment: No, it's not the title that's the problem. I don't think this question is salvageable as an SO question.

Comment: Edited, removing all "my opinion" based stuff.

Comment: I think the current question (after the edit) is fine, and should admit an objective answer. (It is possible, though, that the answer is "nothing would break", which is hard to justify.)

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not in the Haskell2010 standard.

Comment: Put another way: backwards compatibility is not the criterion used to determine whether an extension is enabled in GHC (in other languages the compiler implementation is also the de facto language standard, but that's not the relationship that GHC and haskell have)

Comment: This is definitely not an answer to the question.

Comment: @sandwood the original title was different.